# How to recursion this array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, recursion, hash

I'm wondering how to sum the "analytic" value from this array of hashes with recursion.

**Input :**

```
   [{"id"=>"1234",
     "id_data"=>
      [{"segment"=>{"segment_name"=>"Android"},
        "metrics"=>
          {
            "logins"=>[1000, 2000],
            "sign_ups_conversion"=>{
               "count"=>[500, 200],
               "cost"=>[2, 4]
            }
          },
       },
       {"segment"=>{"segment_name"=>"iOS"},
        "metrics"=>
          {
            "logins"=>[5000, 10000],
            "sign_ups_conversion"=>{
               "count"=>[100, 50],
               "cost"=>[6, 8]
            }
          },
       }
      ]
    },
    {"id"=>"5678",
     "id_data"=>
      [{"segment"=>{"segment_name"=>"Android"},
        "metrics"=>
          {
            "logins"=>[3000, 2000],
            "sign_ups_conversion"=>{
               "count"=>[300, 400],
               "cost"=>[2, 4]
            }
          },
       },
       {"segment"=>{"segment_name"=>"iOS"},
        "metrics"=>
          {
            "logins"=>[5000, 10000],
            "sign_ups_conversion"=>{
               "count"=>[100, 50],
               "cost"=>[6, 8]
            }
          },
       }
      ]
    }]
```

**Output :**

```
    {
      "Android"=>{
        "ids" => ['1234','5678'],
         "segment" => {"segment_name"=>"Android"},
         "id_data" => [{
            "logins" => [4000, 4000], # sum by index from 'Android' logins ("logins"=>[1000, 2000] & "logins"=>[3000, 2000]),
            "sign_ups_conversion" => {
              "count" => [800, 600], # sum by index from 'Android' sign ups count ("count"=>[500, 200] & "count"=>[300, 400])
              "cost" => [4, 8] # sum by index from 'Android' sign ups cost ("cost"=>[2, 4] & "cost"=>[2, 4])
            }  
         }]
      },
      "iOS"=>{
        "ids" => ['1234','5678'],
         "segment" => {"segment_name"=>"iOS"},
         "id_data" => [{
            "logins" => [10000, 20000], # sum by index from 'iOS' logins ("logins"=>[5000, 10000] & "logins"=>[5000, 10000]),
            "sign_ups_conversion" => {
              "count" => [200, 100], # sum by index from 'iOS' sign ups count ("count"=>[100, 50] & "count"=>[100, 50])
              "cost" => [12, 16] # sum by index from 'iOS' sign ups cost ("cost"=>[6, 8] & "cost"=>[6, 8])
            }  
         }]
      }
    }
```

Me, trying to solve it with this methods but it is not counting analytics with hash format (`sign_ups_conversion`) and still figuring it out how the results should be equal to output.

```
    def aggregate_by_segments(stats_array)
      results = {}

      stats_array.each do |stats|
        stats['id_data'].each do |data|
          segment_name = data['segment']['segment_name']
          results[segment_name] ||= {}
          (results[segment_name]['ids'] ||= []) << stats['id']
          results[segment_name]['segment'] ||= data['segment']
          results[segment_name]['id_data'] ||= [{}]
          data['metrics'].each do |metric, values|
            next if skip_metric?(values)
            (results[segment_name]['id_data'][0][metric] ||= []) << values
          end
        end
      end
      sum_segments(results)
    end

    def sum_segments(segments)
      segments.each do |segment, segment_details|
        segment_details['id_data'][0].each do |metric, values|
          segment_details['id_data'][0][metric] = sum_segment_metric(values)
        end
      end
      segments
    end

    def sum_segment_metric(metric_value)
      metric_value.transpose.map { |x| x.reduce(:+) }
    end

    # I skipped hash format for now
    def skip_metric?(metric_values)
      !metric_values.is_a? Array
    end

    ############################################
    # calls it with aggregate_by_segments(input)
    ############################################
```

I believe we should use recursion but i'm still figuring it out, anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a fairly complex set of code and it's asking a lot to ask people to give you the solution.  In any case, the way to solve a big problem is to break it down into several smaller problems.  Why not do that?  By breaking it down into more digestible pieces you can ask specific questions more narrow in scope that are more likely to be answered in a timely manner.  What parts *do* work, if any? What parts don't?  So, what would be the first milestone? (BTW, I don't think you'll need recursion.)

Comment: Besides being quite large, your example data is _very_ specific. Consider posting a more general (and smaller) structure.

Comment: Another thing that might be helpful is you could write in plain English what needs to happen.  Also, never underestimate the power of a rubber duck. ;) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: And, for grouping by segment you could use something like this
`result = input.each_with_object({}) do |id_hash, res|
  id = id_hash['id']
  id_hash['id_data'].each do |id_data|
    segment = id_data['segment']['segment_name']
    res[segment] ||= []
    res[segment] << id_data.merge('id' => id)
  end
end
puts result`

Comment: @KeithBennett sorry it was at midnight. Yes you're right, the question is to broad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

```
    def aggregate_by_segments(stats_array)
      results = {}

      stats_array.each do |stats|
        stats['id_data'].each do |data|
          segment_name = data['segment']['segment_name']
          results[segment_name] ||= {}
          (results[segment_name]['ids'] ||= []) << stats['id']
          results[segment_name]['segment'] ||= data['segment']
          results[segment_name]['id_data'] ||= [{}]
          data['metrics'].each do |metric, values|
            hash_values(results[segment_name]['id_data'][0], metric, values) if values.is_a? Hash
            next if skip_metric?(values)
            (results[segment_name]['id_data'][0][metric] ||= []) << values
          end
        end
      end
      sum_segments(results)
    end

    def hash_values(metrics, metric, hash_values)
      hash_values.each do |k, v|
        next if skip_metric?(v)
        metrics[metric] ||= {}
        (metrics[metric][k] ||= []) << v
      end
    end

    def sum_segments(segments)
      segments.each do |segment, segment_details|
        segment_details['id_data'][0].each do |metric, values|
          segment_details['id_data'][0][metric] = sum_segment_metric(values)
        end
      end
      segments
    end

    def sum_segment_metric(metric_value)
      result = metric_value.transpose.map { |x| x.reduce(:+) } if metric_value.is_a? Array
      result = metric_value.each do |k, v|
        metric_value[k] = sum_segment_metric(v)
      end if metric_value.is_a? Hash
      result
    end

    def skip_metric?(metric_values)
      !metric_values.is_a? Array
    end
```

I know the code is pretty ugly. I will refactor it later :)

Thank you guys for visiting and commenting with constructive feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is how to acces this data structures, a ruby strategy can be iterate over arrays using each and conctenating keys with concatenated hashes like this:

Supposing that your structure is mantained:

**Array[hash[array[hash]]**

```
array_hash.each do |stats|
  stats["id_data"].each do |h|
    puts h["metrics"]["sign_ups_conversion"]
  end
end
# => {"count"=>[500, 200], "cost"=>[2, 4]}
# => {"count"=>[100, 50], "cost"=>[6, 8]}
# => {"count"=>[300, 400], "cost"=>[2, 4]}
# => {"count"=>[100, 50], "cost"=>[6, 8]}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)